Undefined references to OpenCV functions?
I have a simple C++ code 'myscript.cpp':
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "hello everyone" << endl;
    
    // Read an image
    cv::Mat img_test = cv::imread("test.jpg", 0);

    return 0;
}

...and I try to build an .exe using this command out of a .bat script:
g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wall -Wextra -o output.exe myscript.cpp -I C:\CPP\opencv\build\include -L C:\CPP\opencv\build\x64\vc16\lib -l opencv_world490

The opencv library I simply got from opencv-4.9.0-windows.exe downloaded from the official https://opencv.org/releases. As far as I understand it, the compiler/linker is able to find all the given directories and paths, but it does not seem to be able to extract the function definitions. I tried the same using other libraries such as glfw. The error messages read
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1JAyEn.o:myscript.cpp:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1JAyEn.o:myscript.cpp:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1JAyEn.o:myscript.cpp:(.text+0x114): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

How can I fix this? (why is it giving these weird relative paths?)
I am used to do it in a similar fashion on Linux but it seems on Windows every C++ discussion is related to Visual Studio but I cannot use it because of license reasons (VSCode is possible though).

I was going to attempt an answer but I think this is a reasonable duplicate even though it's about the reverse situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70022460/do-libraries-compiled-with-mingw-work-with-msvc

As explained here https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html the download you made is for the Microsoft compiler not for g++. This page also explains how to build the libraries for yourself from source. It's seems to be a complex operation, but it does ensure that the libraries will be compatible with your platform and toolchain.

The libraries that come with a standard opencv Windows installer are for MSVC. For mingw you will have to build them yourself. BTW - if you are on Windows why do you not use VS with MSVC to begin with ? It has a very good and free community-edition.

Your linkage contains C++ object files and C++ libraries originating from different C++ compilers

I appreciate your help guys. I wasn't aware of this basic concept and the compiler error was not giving me a clue in this case.

@colaj That is the reason why I really wanted this question to get out of the staging area successfully even though I expected it to have at least a few reasonable duplicates. I think this is a somewhat common newbie problem and you wrote a good question. I have seen the same problem asked for opencv at least a dozen times. I think this question could be the link that helps new people find the other duplicates that explain the problem.
